# Hosting Django App on AWS EC2 Host

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn, supervisord

There are 3 paths on my AWS EC2 Host:

1) /etc/nginx/ (Contains nginx.conf File)

2) /etc/supervisor/ (Contains supervisord.conf & project.conf files)

3) /home/ec2-user/Project/ (Contains gunicorn_start.sh & project related files)

```
Project
|-- gunicorn_start.sh
|-- project
|   |-- db.sqlite3
|   |-- manage.py
|   |-- miscellaneousConfig
|   |-- README.md
|   |-- static
|      |-- 403.html
|      |-- 50x.html
|      |-- css
|      |-- img
|      |-- js
|   |-- abc1
|      |-- admin.py
|      |-- __init__.py
|      |-- migrations
|         |-- __init__.py
|      |-- models.py
|      |-- templates
|      |   `-- abc1
|      |       |-- file1.html
|      |       `-- file2.html
|      |-- tests.py
|      |-- urls.py
|      `-- views.py
|   |-- abc2
|      |-- functions.py
|      |-- __init__.py
|      |-- settings.py
|      |-- urls.py
|      |-- views.py
|      `-- wsgi.py
|-- logs
|   |-- gunicorn_supervisor.log
|   |-- nginx-access.log
|   `-- nginx-error.log
|-- run
|   `-- gunicorn.sock
```

nginx.conf File(updated):

```
upstream app_server {    
  server unix:/home/ec2-user/Project/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_redirect off;
          if (!-f $request_filename) {
                proxy_pass http://app_server;
                break;
            }
        }

        location /static/ {
          alias /home/ec2-user/Project/project/static/;
        }

        error_page 403 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
           root /home/ec2-user/Project/project/static/;
        }
}
```

gunicorn_start.sh File:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="abc2"                              #Name of the application (*)
DJANGODIR=/home/ec2-user/Project/project            # Django project directory (*)
SOCKFILE=/home/ec2-user/Project/run/gunicorn.sock        # we will communicate using this unix socket (*)
USER=ec2-user                                        # the user to run as (*)
GROUP=webdata                                     # the group to run as (*)
NUM_WORKERS=3                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn (*)
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=abc2.settings             # which settings file should Django use (*)
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=abc2.wsgi                     # WSGI module name (*)

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/ec2-user/Project/venv/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec /home/ec2-user/Project/venv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user $USER \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE
```

project.conf File:

```
[program:project]               # by this name you will call supervisor
command=/home/ec2-user/Project/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind localhost:8000 project.wsgi:application
enviroment=PYTHONPATH=/home/ec2-user/Project/venv/bin  # path to virtualenv
directory=/home/ec2-user/Project/project  # you path to project
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile = /home/ec2-user/Project/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log;        # Where to write log messages
redirect_stderr = true ;          # Save stderr in the same log
```

supervisord.conf File:[Updated]

```
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf

[inet_http_server]
port = 9001
username = ec2-user     # Basic auth username
password =              # Basic auth password

[supervisord]
logfile = /tmp/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes = 50MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel = info
pidfile = /tmp/supervisord.pid
nodaemon = false
minfds = 1024
minprocs = 200
umask = 022
user = ec2-user
identifier = supervisor
directory = /tmp
nocleanup = true
childlogdir = /tmp
strip_ansi = false

[supervisorctl]
serverurl = unix:///home/ec2-user/Project/run/gunicorn.sock
username = ec2-user
```

Access Logs:

```
122.xxs.xxx.xx - - [10/Jan/2016:19:41:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 3795 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
122.xxx.xxx.xx - - [10/Jan/2016:19:41:33 +0000] "GET /%7B%%20static%20'poweredby.png'%20%%7D HTTP/1.1" 400 172 "-" "-"
122.xxx.xxx.xx - - [10/Jan/2016:19:41:33 +0000] "GET /%7B%%20static%20'nginx-logo.png'%20%%7D HTTP/1.1" 400 172 "-" "-"
```

Error Logs:

```
2016/01/10 18:59:04 [error] 3388#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/ec2-user/Project/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xx.xx.xx, server: 52.xx.xx.xx, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ec2-user/Project/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "52.xx.xx.xx"
```

Code Update/Host Changes:
1) 'pip install supervisor'. [created 'supervisord' & 'supervisorctl' available in venv/bin]

2) 'sudo mkdir -p /etc/supervisor/conf.d'

3) 'sudo vim /etc/supervisor/conf.d/project.conf'

4) 'sudo vim /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf'

5) gunicorn project.wsgi:application --bind localhost:8000

```
[2016-01-12 05:41:49 +0000] [8069] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.3
[2016-01-12 05:41:49 +0000] [8069] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (8069)
[2016-01-12 05:41:49 +0000] [8069] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-01-12 05:41:49 +0000] [8074] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8074
```

6) sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

```
[No logs/Error. Prompt Return]
```

7) sudo supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

```
unix:///home/ec2-user/Project/run/gunicorn.sock refused connection
supervisor> 
supervisor> reload
Really restart the remote supervisord process y/N? y
error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 111] Connection refused: file: /usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py line: 228
supervisor>
```

8) 'sudo supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf start project'

```
unix:///home/ec2-user/Project/run/gunicorn.sock refused connection
```

Can you please tell how to resolve this issue ? 
[I want to display file1.html instead of /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html page when I hit 52.xx.xx.xx. Currently, I am seeing 403.html page]

Answer (score 2):

Nginx used for static files. For django project you need to install application server like `uwsgi` or `gunicorn`
It will work by this logic:
`user <-> nginx <-> app_server <-> django`
Here is guide for nginx + gunicorn + django
http://tutos.readthedocs.org/en/latest/source/ndg.html

**UPD for comments**
some config for you, maybe it helps.
Nginx

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name your_public_ip;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/your_nginx.log;

location /media  {
    alias /home/ubuntu/Project/project/media;     
    #It is path to your media, you can check this by 'pwd' command
}

location /static {
    alias /home/ubuntu/Project/project/static_root;
}
    #same
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

install gunicorn and make it autostart by supervisor
`sudo apt-get install supervisor`
open file
`sudo vim /etc/supervisor/conf.d/project.conf`
and write this config

```
[program:project] #by this name you will call supervisor
command=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind localhost:8000 project.wsgi:application    
enviroment=PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin    #path to virtualenv
directory=/home/ubuntu/project_folder/project  #you path to project
user=ubuntu  #your user
```

start it
`sudo supervisorctl start project`

also comand for supervisor:
`sudo supervisorctl reload`
`sudo supervisorctl status`
`sudo supervisorctl reread`
`sudo supervisorctl update`

Comment: Is it necessary for the 'project' path to be: /var/www/ ?

Comment: When I am trying to run 'gunicorn project.wsgi:application' from path '/home/ec2-user/project/', it is throwing a long error trace: venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()        ImportError: No module named wsgi

Comment: `No module named wsgi` wsgi it is name of app file in django, contains in project folder, near `settings.py`, you cal it from wrong path. So prepare for dificult task. When I upload first time, I do it all day. I recomend you do all thing from tutorial step by step, and google erors, which your will have

Comment: When I try the command: ' systemctl enable gunicorn_project', it says  -bash: systemctl: command not found. Can you please provide some alternative/suggestion on how to install this ?

Comment: you can check in google, this problem, it will be in first page. But honestly I dont use it, in what step you stay? You need to config nginx, config gunciorn, then add this in supervisor, phoro auto start. You can check another guide for this problem, when I do it first time, I read like 3 or 4 guides :)

Comment: here is cool guide too http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Comment: I have configured nginx, configured gunicorn. But for adding this in supervisor for auto start, the previous guide suggest to use 'systemctl'. But that command is not available on amazon aws ec2 host and I am not sure how to go about this. Can you please suggest ?

Comment: I have created a new service file similar to '/usr/lib/systemd/system/gunicorn_ourcase.service' from previous guide but I am not sure how to enable it(the guide suggests use 'systemctl'). Google is suggesting that systemctl/systemd are not available on some machines. Can you please suggest alternative ?

Comment: just dont use systemctl, folow other steps, it will works. You need to try more options, and when you stuck, asking

Comment: Can you please help in resolving the Permission Issue(Updated Error Log in the Original Question) ? [if i comment the line 'root /home/ec2-user/project/static/;' from the conf file, the error would be resolved, But this path is required]

Comment: SELinux is disabled. On running 'sudo echo 1 > /selinux/enforce', it says '-bash: /selinux/enforce: Permission denied'

Comment: check answer, try my config

Comment: installed supervisor using the command 'pip install supervisor'(This made 'supervisord' & 'supervisorctl' commands available in venv/bin). Then 'mkdir -p /etc/supervisor/conf.d'. Then 'sudo vim /etc/supervisor/conf.d/project.conf'. Then edited the contents of the file as u suggested. Then, on running 'sudo supervisorctl start project' command, it says 'localhost:9001 refused connection'. I guess supervisord command also needs to be executed before supervisorctl.(Not sure on which file it needs to be run)

Comment: running 'supervisorctl reread' resulted in 'error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 111] Connection refused: file: /usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py line: 575' if it helps.